# Using Text-overflow: ellipsis; in percentage sized div

Tags: html, css, flexbox, ellipsis

So I have three divs on a page displayed using flexbox. They have equal flex:shrink, and flex:grow. They have different flex:basis;. Inside of one of them can be very short text names, and long ones.

I want the text to be placed in there and use the 85% its given, and not expand the parent div of '.one'. Not sure how to go about it. Thanks.

Goal: Divs that resize and shrink according to flexbox, BUT the text in div one doesn't expand div one at all. If its too long, it follows text-overflow rules and shortens. If you shorten the name in one, you will see the difference.

```
.Name{
  margin: 0px;
    width: 85%;
    max-height: 25px;
    font-size: 18px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/109154/

Comment: What is you end goal? The div is behaving as I would expect as you have set for that div to shrink but have allowed it to grow to a max of 650px.  I don't fully understand what you want - if you want it to be a percentage width set a percentage width?

Comment: Use word-break: break-all; to see the same effect even with long word

Comment: I wanted the text to have no effect on the div. Basically the div doesn't get bigger because of a bigger name. It just sizes according to the screen size, flexbox and puts the text overflow rule on the name.

Comment: I will try that @Naga Sai A

Comment: Use a percentage width then? https://jsfiddle.net/t29ffzan/ - I added a min-width and removed flex-shrink

Comment: @Will remove white-space: nowrap; and add word-break: break-all;  https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/YaMdgw